# Package for professional writing of electron configurations?

Tags: mhchem, chemistry, physics

I am writing a paper that deals partly with X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS). XPS results are usually described with the respective elements and the electron configuration of the measured electron. This looks usually like C\textsubscript{1s}.

In general, this is fine for me, but it does not feel very professional. All my other chemical formulas are now written using the package mhchem, which is generally very professional. Unfortunately, it does not seem as if mhchem supports writing of electron configurations. It does not seem very professional to write all chemical formulas with one package but not the electron configuration. It is possible to write \ce{C_{1s}} as a workaround, but that doesn't feel very professional neither.

My question is, is there a chemistry package that supports writing of electron states better?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
H\textsubscript{2}O

\ce{H2O}

C\textsubscript{1s}

\ce{C_{1s}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) I know of no such package. But I don't see anything against writing `\ce{C_{1s}}`. Is there a particular reason why you don't like it?

Comment: @clemens Any chance that you have included that in `chemformula` (or another package of the bundle) and can answer that? If not, we could treat that as a *feature request* ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B actually I'm not quite sure what exactly the OP wants. I don't think I've ever seen [electron configurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) as subscripts. (However, `mhchem` and `chemformula` both can easily do this and the question even states this.) Since @Dietmar never responded to my comment I am reluctant to post an answer based on speculation...

Comment: I've no idea what is 'not professional' here: what's wrong with your input as suggested?